# Доступ к значениям, переданным в командной строке

Tags: wpf, .net, c#

Имеется приложение WPF, получающее данные, как параметр командной строки, при запуске.
Как и где удобнее всего хранить эти данные, чтобы иметь к ним доступ из всех частей приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удобнее всего хранить в файле приложения. Это позволит получить доступ к нему из всех мест программного кода. Также можно хранить в ресурсах отдельного окна, компонента и т.д.. Еще одним способом хранения являются настройки приложения. По последнему следует посмотреть, как работать с классом

```
System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyCollection
```

Пример, как это может быть выполнено, в случае использования класса `SettingsPropertyCollection`

```
Dictionary<string, string> options = this.PrepareCommandLine(args);

System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyCollection properties = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties;

foreach (System.Configuration.SettingsProperty property in properties)
{
    if (options.ContainsKey(property.Name.ToString()))
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default[property.Name.ToString()] = options[property.Name.ToString()];
    }
}
```